# Query Date dimension for days during past 5 months

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

Is this the most trustworthy and efficient method of extracting the days for the past 5 months from a `Date` dimension

```
{DESCENDANTS( 
    Tail([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].Members,5), 
    [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day] 
    )}
```

I believe the dimension I'm querying is relatively standard:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may prefer this alternative syntax:

```
{
     DESCENDANTS( 
        {[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].LastChild.Lag(5) : 
         [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].LastChild}
        , [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day] 
    )
}
```

and optionally change

```
[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].LastChild
```

by another member expression

Comment: +1 I like the use of the range operator `:` ...think I need to use it more often as it seems to make the script a little more readable